# Can I have 2 clash of clan accounts on my one device with 2 different Game centre accounts?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to start another Clash of Clans account on the same device, but with a different game centre account, but every time I log in to my new account it goes back to my old coc account.

How do I get a new Clash of Clans account, on the same device, with a new game centre account?

Comment: Uninstall, reinstall **then** log into the new account. We have a dupe of this somewhere... Lemmie search.

Comment: so I I want to log back into my old acc will it still be there ?? on my other game centre account

Comment: @aytimothy he doesn't have to re-install it he just has to clear the Data

Comment: @Eisler485 Doesn't work like that for older versions of iOS, which I'm stuck with.

Comment: @aytimothy okay, I didn't know that...

Answer (score 7):

### Yes, you can!

But you have to log out of the first account and remove all data as accessing an existing village with a new account will bind that village to the account instead of creating a new one.

---

> So, how do I do it?

Simply log out of your current Game Center account **and** uninstall Clash of Clans, as this removes all village and device identification numbers.

After that, log into a new Game Center account and reinstall/open the game.

**Note:** If you have already have a village and accidentally opened it with a new account, that account will have that village *also* bound to it. In this case, you'll need to create *another* Game Center account.

> So, if I wanted to switch back to my old village, can I?

Yes, and you don't need to reinstall. Just open Clash of Clans logged into the new account and it'll ask you whether you would like to switch villages. In this case, select **Yes**.

Answer (score 0):

the above answer answers the question but with a long method.

you will be frequently be changing your account*. so instead of going through a long process given above use this:

**clearing the data and launching that app is definitely fast method to switch accounts. It is faster than reinstalling the app.**

there is **another method** that can do switching which is even faster than clear data but **I don't know whether super-cell gets information** that We have 2 accounts.

> **Warning: following method is quickest but doesnot gaurantee safety of account**
>
> that method is directly switch the account from google+ signin button. it       will ask for confirmation and tell you to type "DELETE". this switches the account but I don't know what this delete exactly mean.
> Does it mean that device data is cleared or the account data will eventually be wiped off is still unclear.

[image]

*assuming you will use both accounts every day.

Comment: This works on Android, however the OP was asking about Game Centre - an IOS tool. The steps described would allow you to create an entirely new village on an Android device... HOWEVER you should first Disconnect the account using the settings button.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is log out of Game Center and log in with the account you want, u will see a bubble that asked if u want to load the old acc, press yes, than it will ask to confirm, it's ok don't freak out , u can get to both of ur villages safely , no need to delete and reinstall. I have 2 clash accounts I access with the one device , different emails, it's annoying to keep changing centres so it's best if u can get a 2nd device.

Comment: I think this was down voted because it presumes you already have created a second gamecenter account. But +1 on the comment about how annoying it is to change between accounts on GameCenter. Android Play account switch is much easier and all done within the Clash of Clans app.